# Pandas dataframe to Snowflake is not working on DATE datatypes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a dataframe with column 'DATE_REGISTERED'.The format of the data in this dataframe is 'YYYY-MM-DD'. I am trying to use write_pandas method to load this data into a Snowflake table. But I am unable to achieve this as the code is throwing below error.

[image]

The input data is '2021-02-10' (10th of Feb 2021)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I am able to fix this issue by simply converting the datatype of the column in DF to string. This worked and resolved my issue.